# Turn wrong date string to nearest valid one

Tags: c#, .net, date

For example I have 31.09.2017 (which is NON existent date) and that string's      `DateTime.ParseExact("31.09.2017", "dd.MM.yyyy", null);` returns `System.FormatException` exception. Is there a way to turn 31.09.2017 into 30.09.2017 and do the same for all such wrong dates? For example like "round" works: to move to previous month's last day or next month's first day.

Comment: In C, there's `mktime`, which goes for a third option: e.g. 40 September is counted as 10 days after 30 September. I don't know off hand of C# libraries implementing this, but if there are, it may be good to state whether this would be okay.

Comment: This seems the solution for me. I just want incorrect date to become correct in some reasonable conditions.. For example 45.324.43 will be error in my imaginary case, but 40.09.2017 should work as you've said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following technique :

```
DateTime temp;
if (!DateTime.TryParse("31.09.2017", out temp))
    temp = GetValidDate("31.09.2017");

DateTime GetValidDate(string _date)
{
    int day, year, month;
    day = int.Parse(_date.Substring(0, 2));
    month = int.Parse(_date.Substring(3, 2));
    year = int.Parse(_date.Substring(6, 4));

    return new DateTime(year, month, Math.Min(day, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)));
}
```

Comment: Think I'll stick with the solution you've suggested with a bit changed parsing. The part `new DateTime(year, month, Math.Min(day, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)));` gives the result I want in current situation: the last day of previous month in case the day is incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: It's just the idea, you can expand and make it more efficient according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

The result may be unpredictable but your could split parts, convert to an int, then ensure that each part is within the correct range, then create a new string to parse. I suspect you only need to do this for the first 2 parts (dd and MM) and if outside of the range just set to the closest bounding value.

Comment: I get it.. Just was wondering maybe there are some ready packages or extension methods for such case.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [custom format provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it with `DateTime.ParseExact` however it may not work across cultures and may still throw exceptions like `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.` depending on how you implement.

```
DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)
```

An [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3).